# Remove all XSLFTextRun from a XSLFTextParagraph in Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Is there any way to remove all text runs (of type `XSLFTextRun`) from a `XSLFTextParagraph` in Apache POI 3.16?

Comment: there's a `XSLFTextParagraph.clearButKeepProperties()` method, but it's on package visibility, so you would need a helper class in the `org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel` package. I guess removing all the text paragraphs via `XSLFTextShape.setText("")` is not an option.

Comment: We have an `XSLFTextBox` with potentially multiple paragraphs, and each paragraph may contain multiple text runs, all with the same style (same font, etc.). We want to replace the text of each paragraph. We currently do that by storing the text in the first text run and clearing all the other text runs. We're just wondering if there's a cleaner solution.